# Issues importing dateutil when using PyInstaller

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyinstaller, python-dateutil

So, I am trying to create an exe using PyInstaller.  My application worked fine before adding a feature with `matplotlib`.  Now I get an import error with `dateutil`.  I have added `dateutil` to the hidden imports and PyInstaller keeps returning the following error:

```
ERROR: Hidden import 'dateutil' not found
```

I did some drilling down and just made a simple file to recreate the issue and see if it was the `matplotlib` package or something due to `dateutil`.

The following script `hello.py` runs in my environment with no import errors:

```
import dateutil
print "Hello World"
```

When building with PyInstaller with the following command:

```
pyinstaller --onefile hello.py
```

I still get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named dateutil
```

I have found some hints that there might be some existing problems importing `dateutil` but nothing that helps my specific case.  I have tried making a hook for `dateutil` and it doesn't seem to get run by PyInstaller, so I worry importing `dateutil` is not the name PyInstaller sees it as, but I don't know what else it could be (I tried `python_dateutil` and `python-dateutil` as well, neither worked).  I also tried the --debug flag to see if I got more information, but all I saw was:

```
LOADER: Running hello.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named dateutil
```

I am missing something and I can't figure it out.  I hope someone out there can help me out.

Note: Using Python 2.7.9, PyInstaller 3.0 and dateutil is version 2.4.2

Thanks!

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue with the `yaml` module (PyYAML). Perhaps they have something in common...

Comment: I've managed to solve my issue by installing the `python3-yaml` system package. Maybe if you install `python-dateutil` with `apt-get`, `yum` or whatever...

Comment: @albertedevigo I did try `python-dateutil` and it didn't help me. I installed manually because I don't have the ability to use `apt-get` or `yum` but I can't imagine that makes a difference.  Thanks for the suggestion though :).